# Problems getting updated information with PHP exec()

Tags: php

I have simple code that uses exec() to set a variable with some system information (like current IP.) I execute the code and display the information. I change the IP address of the computer and rerun the code. I'm using unset() to clear the variable before executing the code, however, it still displays the old information. How do I obtain the current information using exec()? Thanks in advance and sorry for the noob-iness.

```
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" onclick="showip()">Get IP</button>

  <script>
  function showip(){
     <?php
        unset($return);
        unset($ip);
        exec('wget https://ipinfo.io/ip -qO -', $return);
        $ip = $return[0];
     ?>
     curip = <?php echo(json_encode($ip, JSON_HEX_TAG)); ?>;
     alert("The current IP is "+curip);
   }
  </script>
```

Comment: PHP runs on the server...

Comment: Which IP address do you want to obtain. As a server running inside a VPN, you may want to obtain the public IP, or IP inside the VPN, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP runs on the server, this is why you're always getting the same IP address.

If you want the client's IP address you can use

```
$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]
```

> ['REMOTE_ADDR'](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)
>
> The IP address from which the user is viewing the current page.

Another solution would be to make an [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX) request to `https://ipinfo.io/ip`.

```
function showip() {
    fetch("https://ipinfo.io/ip")
    .then(function(response) {
        return response.text()
    })
    .then(function(ip) {
        alert("The current IP is " + ip)
    })
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. It is the server I'm looking for. A little background, I'm trying to create a touchscreen interface to change the VPN on a raspberry pi. I have a console window that displays current status and other information as the user changes the VPN. But as I change the VPN the exec() still shows the old IP, even though I can see from the CLI it has changed.

Comment: Maybe `wget` returns a cached response from the server. Have you tried adding `--no-cache` to prevent it from caching?

Comment: Thanks for all your help. The AJAX request took care of the problem. Still weird wget would cache it like that (even with --no-cache.)

Answer (score 0):

A server may have multiple IP addresses, including at least the public IP and the local(VPN) IP.
I guess the question for obtain public IP has been answered. If you want to obtain the local IP(inside the VPN) of the server. You may try use 'ip addr' like this:

```
function ips(){
  $ips = [];
  exec('ip addr', $lines);
  foreach($lines as $line){
    $fields = explode(" ",trim($line));
    if($fields[0] == 'inet'){
      $ip = explode("/",$fields[1])[0];
      $ifname = $fields[count($fields)-1];
      $ips[$ifname] = $ip;
    }
  }
  return $ips;
}
```

This will return all local IP(v4) of each interfaces. If you want to have IPv6, just change 'inet' to 'inet6'.